# Google Chrome Issue With Css And JScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, google-chrome

I have working on photo gallery where about 44 images in gallery each images are 300kb sizes.
The images are hide by css file as under:

```
.koImg1
{
 display:none;

}
.koImg2
{
 display:none;

}

.koImg3
{
 display:none;

}
```

The above are small example for your consideration actually I have hide 44 images as above. And animated the same as Jscript file as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Img1").hover(function(){
$("#kImg1").show();
$("#kImg1").animate({width:'765px',height:'435px'},1000);

});
$("#Img1").mouseleave(function(){
$("#kImg1").hide();

});
$("#Img2").hover(function(){
$("#kImg2").show();

$("#kImg2").animate({width:'765px',height:'435px'},1000);
});
$("#Img2").mouseleave(function(){
$("#kImg2").hide();
});
});
```

I add here in details that how I works on:

```
<table style="width:100%; background-color:Black;"><tr><td style="width:100%">
<table style="width:800px; height:450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border- style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:Red;"><tr><td style="width:800px;  height:450px;">
<asp:Panel ID="Pnl1" runat="server" CssClass ="Pnl1" Width="780" Height="445" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="yellow">
<center>

    <asp:Image ID="kImg1" CssClass="koImg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img1.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="white"  />
    <asp:Image ID="kImg2" CssClass="koImg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img2.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="white"  />
    <asp:Image ID="kImg3" CssClass="koImg3" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img3.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="white"  />

</center>
</asp:Panel>
</td></tr></table> //THIS TABLE IS THE CONTAINER OF DISPLAYS OF IMAGES

//AND BELOW TABLES IS THE HOVER TYPE DISPLAYS. MEANS THE BELOW TABLES CONTAINS 44    IMAGES
//IF I HOVER ON ONE IMAGES THAN IT WILL DISPLAYS THE SAME IMAGES IN ABOVE TABLE...

<table style="width:800px; height:110px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border- style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:White;"><tr><td style="width:800px;  height:110px;">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="780" Height="105" BorderStyle="solid"  BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="green" ScrollBars="Auto">
    <asp:Image ID="Img1"  CssClass="Img1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img1.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid"  BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="white"  />
    <asp:Image ID="Img2" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img2.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="white"  />
    <asp:Image ID="Img3" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img3.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="white"  />
</asp:Panel>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
```

The same with 1 to 44 images. It works well on the local server and with Mozilla Firefox on the production server. It doesn't work well with Google Chrome on the production server.

On the local server Google Chrome works well but on the production server it hides and animates only files 1 to 26 but not files 27 to 44.

I think it might be a problem of images taking time for loading on server. Don’t know how to overcome?. What is the exact problem and how to overcome it?.

Comment: `Jscript` only works in `IE`, so what exactly is it `javascript` || `Jscript`

Comment: Please add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It seems classes/ids are inconsistant

Comment: @jai, Jscript is works on IE as well as on Google-Chrome... test it....

Comment: @JNF, If you are right than tell me hows it works on Mozila FireFox on Net?. It is works well on local google chrome server but not net server. hows it possible if classes/ids are inconsistant than works well on local server with google-chrome?.

Comment: @Jai, It is JScript.....

Answer (score 2):

Am I getting this right that you have 44 instances of the same code? If that is the case you REALLY need to simplify things. You need to add more code to your question so people can see how things are organised.

First for the CSS classes why don't you have a class added to all the images, and instead having to do `.koImg1, .koImg2, .koImg3 ...{display none}` you just do:

```
.hiddenImg{
   display:none;
}
```

And in html add that class to each of the images

```
<asp:Image ID="kImg2" CssClass="koImg2 hiddenImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="PAlbum/BMeet/Img2.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="white"  />
```

and add it to all the containers you need to hide.

I'm not sure how the ASP code you edited in works, but I'm definitely thinking that you need one function to handle all the hover states.

Comment: see my edited question, your ideas is completely hide the container of images where I just want to hide only images not container and displays the images one by one at hover event.

Comment: no, i was thinking to add `imgContainer` on each of the images.